# Assign/return value onClick event, return it send/receive on DependencyService

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to assign a value with a click event in a custom DialogAlert, return the value and, with a dependency service, read in another class.

this class calls the dependencyService method:

```
bool respuesta;
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    respuesta = await DisplayAlert(Strings.turno_confirmartitulo, Strings.turno_confirmarmensaje,
                                    Strings.si, Strings.btncancelar);
}
else
{
    respuesta = DependencyService.Get<intTbsMensajes> ().MostrarMensaje(
        Strings.turno_confirmartitulo, Strings.turno_confirmarmensaje);
}
if(respuesta) {// Do something}
```

and this method builds the DialogAlert:

```
public bool MostrarMensaje(string p_titulo, string p_mensaje)
{
    objBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Forms.Context, Resource.Style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
    objBuilder.SetTitle(p_titulo);
    objBuilder.SetMessage(p_mensaje);
    objBuilder.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_question);
    objBuilder.SetCancelable(false);
    bool respuesta = false;

    objDialog = objBuilder.Create();
    objDialog.SetButton((int)(DialogButtonType.Positive), Strings.si, (sender, e) =>
   {
       respuesta = true;
   });

    objDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, Strings.no, (sender, e) =>
   {
       respuesta = false;
   });

    objDialog.Show();
    return respuesta;
}
```

really, I don't know what is wrong. I hope that somebody can help me, please :)
Thanks so much

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, Mark. I'm not getting any error. But it always return false pressing any button (excuse my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an modal style Alert by using `AutoResetEvent` and then wrapping it in a `Task` and call it Async style.

Here is how I would structure it:

#### Example:

```
AlertDialog objDialog;
public async Task<bool> MostrarMensaje(string p_titulo, string p_mensaje)
{
    objDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Forms.Context)
       .SetTitle(p_titulo)
       .SetMessage(p_mensaje)
       .SetCancelable(false)
       .Create();
    bool respuesta = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        objDialog.SetButton((int)(DialogButtonType.Positive), "yes", (sender, e) =>
        {
           respuesta = true;
           waitHandle.Set();
        });

        objDialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, "no", (sender, e) =>
        {
           respuesta = false;
           waitHandle.Set();
        });

        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            objDialog.Show();
        });
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    });
    objDialog.Dispose();
    return respuesta;
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var result = await DependencyService.Get<intTbsMensajes>().MostrarMensaje("Stack", "Overflow");
Log.Debug("respuesta", result.ToString());
```

#### Result:

[image]

```
[respuesta] True
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this

Comment: The AlertDialog works! but I have another problem. Execution contunies without waiting the DependencyService. How I can wait and take the value returned?

Comment: @SamirRíos You have to call it with `await`, see the "Usage:" section in my answer. Then the method will not return until `waitHandle.Set();` is executed.